# Browser is closed only if test passed on VM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, chromedriver, specflow

I use `driver.Dispose();` and using ChromeDriver. But the browser is closed only if the test passed. On the VM if a test failed, the browser is still open. If I run tests from Visual Studio on local machine, browser is closed if test passed or failed.

```
[AfterScenario]
public void DisposeWebDriver()
{
    foreach (CommonTests ct in _tests) {
       try {
            Exception ex = this.ScenarioContext.TestError != null ? this.ScenarioContext.TestError : null;
            ct.TakeScreenshot(this.ScenarioContext, ex);
            ct.Dispose();
       } catch (Exception exception) { Console.WriteLine(exception.Message); }
    }
}
```

---

```
public void Dispose()
{
   if (null != WebDriver) WebDriver.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure TakeScreenshot doesn't throw an error on the VM? :)

Comment: No it just says cannot locate element ID and times out. After the timeout it goes to the next test in that group leaving the Chrome window open.

Comment: There's your answer. If it fails at TakeScreenshot it won't execute the next line (dispose).

Comment: Commented out that piece of code but no luck, not sure why it is happening only on the VM.

Answer (score 1):

For me as it turned out it was a chrome driver version issue, after updating the chrome driver the issue was resolved.